# How to share single StyleSheet among multiple item-widgets?

Tags: python, pyqt

The code below creates `QTreeWidget` with two `QComboBoxes` set as its item-widgets.
There was a QSS styleSheet assigned to the first ComboBox.

**Question**: Since `QTreeWidgetItem` which is the parent to ComboBoxes  does not have `.setStyleSheet()` method I have to iterate through each item-widget to assign or to modify its styleSheets. Needless to say this exra-computing slows down GUI's respond time. Instead it would be great if all the Item's comboboxes would share the same styleSheet. So changing a single ComboBox's styleSheet would change the appearance of all the item's Comboboxes at once. How to achieve it?

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

class Tree(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Tree, self).__init__()
        for each in ['Item_1','Item_2','Item_3','Item_4','Item_5']:
            item=QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem([each])
            self.addTopLevelItem(item)
            combo1=QtGui.QComboBox()
            combo2=QtGui.QComboBox()
            self.setItemWidget(item, 1, combo1)
            self.setItemWidget(item, 2, combo2)
            comboStyle="QComboBox {background-color: #7A7A7A; border: 1px solid black;}"
            combo1.setStyleSheet(comboStyle)
        self.setColumnCount(5)
        self.resize(360,240)
        self.show()

tree=Tree()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I don't see a problem with setting styles individually so far as CPU usage is concerned, and may be more explicit. However, the following works: you set the style for the parent widget, and children will inherit these styles unless otherwise specified

```
class Tree(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Tree, self).__init__()
        comboStyle="QComboBox {background-color: #7A7A7A; border: 1px solid black;}"
        self.setStyleSheet(comboStyle)
        for each in ['Item_1','Item_2','Item_3','Item_4','Item_5']:
            item=QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem([each])
            self.addTopLevelItem(item)
            combo1=QtGui.QComboBox()
            combo2=QtGui.QComboBox()
            self.setItemWidget(item, 1, combo1)
            self.setItemWidget(item, 2, combo2)
        self.setColumnCount(5)
        self.resize(360,240)
        self.show()
```

Note that for me this resulted in changing the column widths, so you may need a `resizeColumnToContents()`.

Comment: You could also subclass the combo box, but that seems like unnecessary extra lines of code.

Comment: Thanks! But setting the styleSheet on `QTreeWidget` level will make all its items and all items item-widgets to share a single stylesheet. I want only the item-widgets to share a stylesheet. By other words, a single stylesheet's scope should only be extending on to a single `QTreeWidgetItem`. For example: if there are five ComboBoxes assigned as item-widgets then only these five comboboxes share the same stylesheet.

Comment: You mean some combo boxes should have this style and some should not? In that case, the only way to save code lines would be to subtype comboBox, but I don't think it will make any difference to your GUI responsiveness either way.

Comment: No, all the comboBoxes should have a stylesheet applied. But. One stylesheet per TreeWidgetItem.

Comment: If they are to have different stylesheets, then you need to apply them individually.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it using signals/slots to change and reapply the stylesheet to the sub-classed widgets. I like this approach since there is no need to iterate through all `QListWidgetsItems` and its `ItemWidgets`. The `ItemWidgets` are listening for the Signal and update their styles all by themselves. I also implemented here a mechanism of selecting `QTreeWidgetItem` when one of its `Item-Widgets` is clicked.

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

class LineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, tree, item):
        QtGui.QLineEdit.__init__(self)
        self.tree=tree
        self.item=item
        self.restyle()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('click!'),self)

    def restyle(self): 
        if self.item.isSelected(): bgColor='#7A7A7A'
        elif self.tree.indexFromItem(self.item).row()%2: bgColor='#1F1F1F'
        else: bgColor='#262626'

        stylesheet="QLineEdit {{background-color: {0}; border: 1px solid black;}}".format(bgColor) 
        self.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
        for i in range(5): self.item.setBackgroundColor(i, QtGui.QColor(bgColor))

class ComboBox(QtGui.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, tree, item):
        QtGui.QComboBox.__init__(self)
        self.tree=tree
        self.item=item
        self.restyle()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event): 
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('click!'),self)

    def restyle(self): 
        if self.item.isSelected(): bgColor='#7A7A7A'
        elif self.tree.indexFromItem(self.item).row()%2: bgColor='#1F1F1F'
        else: bgColor='#262626'

        stylesheet="QComboBox {{background-color: {0}; border: 1px solid black;}}".format(bgColor) 
        self.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
        for i in range(5): self.item.setBackgroundColor(i, QtGui.QColor(bgColor))

class Tree(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Tree, self).__init__()
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.Base)
        p = self.palette()
        p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), QtGui.QColor("#0F0F0F"))
        self.setPalette(p)        
        self.setColumnCount(5)
        for each in ['Item_1','Item_2','Item_3','Item_4','Item_5']:
            item=QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem([each])
            self.addTopLevelItem(item)
            combo=ComboBox(self, item)
            lineEdit=LineEdit(self, item)

            combo.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL('selectionChanged!'), combo.restyle)
            lineEdit.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL('selectionChanged!'), lineEdit.restyle)

            self.setItemWidget(item, 1, combo)
            self.setItemWidget(item, 2, lineEdit)

            self.connect(combo, QtCore.SIGNAL('click!'), self.select)
            self.connect(lineEdit, QtCore.SIGNAL('click!'), self.select)

        self.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.emitOnChange)

        self.resize(480,120)
        self.show()

    def select(self, itemWidget):
        for i in range(self.topLevelItemCount()):
            self.topLevelItem(i).setSelected(False)

        itemWidget.item.setSelected(True)

    def emitOnChange(self, arg=None):
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('selectionChanged!'),self)

tree=Tree()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```